# How do I keep runoff rain from flooding my carport?

Tags: flooding

Once the drain and ditches fill up in front of my property, water comes all the way down carport and leaves approx.a 2 inch water line around foundation and steps. City tells me it's a county problem,county tells me it's the city's. Driveway sits low so all rain comes in like a river.

Comment: If the water did hit your house, where would it go? Regrading the site so that there is a path around your house (i.e. a swale) is the only long term fix because water will always run downhill.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can't get the political problem solved (letters to the editor time, perhaps), you need to address the part where "driveway sits low so all the rain comes in like a river" (though you might also take the practical citizen approach and see if there's anything blocking the ditches and drains that you can, as concerned citizen, remove on your own.)

You'd be looking to build a smooth, drive-over-able, dam across your driveway. You may need to extend it with smooth, mow-able wings onto your lawn/yard. Alternatively, you make a wide smooth ditch that you can drive through, again extending of into the yard so the water has somewhere to go. In either case the aim is not to "just stop" the water (that is a game you almost always will lose at eventually) but rather to divert the water around your house/carport to somewhere less problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to this post, but it may help someone to say I solved an annoying flooding problem by having an asphalt lip installed the length of the driveway in front of the carport.  It directs water towards drainage and also helps keep sticks and leaves from blowing in.  I'm always thinking it's one of the best ideas I've had around here.